# ASP.Net Javascript code throws weird exception (even when commented!)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, devexpress

I'm working on a website in ASP in which I use Javascript code in the HEAD section. 
I'm trying to implement a context menu of my own, so I wrote the logic for it in this section. My code is as follows :

```
function fileGridGrouping_ContextMenu(s, e) {
       if(e.objectType != "row") return;
       fileGridGrouping.SetFocusedRowIndex(e.index);
       lastFileId = "<%# fileGridGrouping.GetRowValues(fileGridGrouping.FocusedRowIndex, "ID").ToString() %>";
    }
```

As you can see, I'm also calling some C# code in the background, which is used to get the ID of the selected row. The following code throws an exception, which is to be expected if the FocusedRowIndex isn't initialized :

[image: First exception]

For testing purposes, I then decide to not use the FocusedRowIndex anymore, but to always get the first row :

```
function fileGridGrouping_ContextMenu(s, e) {
       if(e.objectType != "row") return;
       fileGridGrouping.SetFocusedRowIndex(e.index);
       lastFileId = "<%# fileGridGrouping.GetRowValues(0, "ID").ToString() %>";
    }
```

This code throws no exception, which does prove that the issue came from FocusedRowIndex not being initialized (thus set to -1). Fine enough! I decide to fix it very easily :

```
function fileGridGrouping_ContextMenu(s, e) {
       if(e.objectType != "row") return;
       fileGridGrouping.SetFocusedRowIndex(e.index);
       if ("<%# fileGridGrouping.FocusedRowIndex %>" <= 0) return;
       lastFileId = "<%# fileGridGrouping.GetRowValues(0, "ID").ToString() %>";
    }
```

But, surprisingly, the same exception is thrown, at the exact same spot. 
As a final try to understand what exactly is happening, I decide to comment the culprit :

```
function fileGridGrouping_ContextMenu(s, e) {
       if(e.objectType != "row") return;
       fileGridGrouping.SetFocusedRowIndex(e.index);
       if ("<%# fileGridGrouping.FocusedRowIndex %>" <= 0) return;
       //lastFileId = "<%# fileGridGrouping.GetRowValues(fileGridGrouping.FocusedRowIndex, "ID").ToString() %>";
    }
```

And now this is just outright weird :

[image: Weird exception]

The commented line throws an exception, as if the commented code was actually run by the website. I tried restarting Visual Studio, rebuilding everything from scratch, but the same thing happens again and again.

To add to the weirdness, all this code is run BEFORE any clicking actually happens, but when the page is loading. The function fileGridGrouping_ContextMenu() is supposed to be called when a right click is done on the table in the page, but this code is run BEFORE anything actually happens. I'm guessing there's some kind of compilation or something of the sort happening?

I have no idea what's going on, and no clue on how to fix it.

**EDIT** : I now fixed the issue by changing most of the code. Turns out I wasn't using the best functions to do what I wanted. Oops. Thanks to all those who helped me!
Here is the working code :

```
function fileGridGrouping_ContextMenu(s, e) {
       if(e.objectType != "row") return;
       fileGridGrouping.SetFocusedRowIndex(e.index);
       fileGridGrouping.GetRowValues(fileGridGrouping.GetFocusedRowIndex(), "ID", OnGetRowValues);
    }

    function OnGetRowValues(value) {
        lastFileId = value;
    }
```

Comment: For a better understandig: The functions you wrote are in C# or in Javascript?

Comment: The functions are written in Javascript, but do call some C# code in the quotes.

Comment: Just Clear cache from browser and reload again. May be its takes from Cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you have a Null values :

```
fileGridGrouping.GetRowValues(fileGridGrouping.FocusedRowIndex, "ID") //return Null
(Null).ToString() //Exception
```

try to use this line instead:

```
'<%# (fileGridGrouping.GetRowValues(fileGridGrouping.FocusedRowIndex, "ID") ?? "").ToString() %>';
```

Comment: That fixed the issue! It did not make my program work (I'll edit the first post to show what I changed) but it did prevent the exception from being thrown. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You've got some improperly nested quotes, here:

```
"<%# fileGridGrouping.GetRowValues(fileGridGrouping.FocusedRowIndex, "ID").ToString() %>";
//                                   See the syntax highlighting here ^
```

Replace that line with:

```
'<%# fileGridGrouping.GetRowValues(fileGridGrouping.FocusedRowIndex, "ID").ToString() %>';
```

(Notice the single quotes (<kbd>'</kbd>) in that last line)

The reason you're still getting the error when the line is commented, is that any code in these blocks: `<%# %>` is run server-side. It basically doesn't care about the JavaScript comment in front of it.

Comment: That's a good lead, but I just tried switching the quotes for the singles quotes exactly as you posted, and the same exception is still thrown. I actually thought about that at first, but even though the syntax highlighting basically tells me it's wrong, I have a lot of code written this way, and everything works perfectly except this little sample.

Comment: Darnit, Then I don't know what's going on. I'll leave this answer here, for the part about it running when commented.

Comment: Thank you for the comment explanation indeed! I learned something today :)